# Parsing HTML using Beautifulsoup with several Span properties

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the 'new/used' element from the following webpage using beautiful soup. I manage to extract alot from it already where the span has only one element (see code for extracting price). However, the new/used split has several span properties that I am having trouble extracting. Website example is below:

http://www.bidorbuy.co.za/item/287281843/BEDS_DOUBLE_BED_POCKET_SPRING_BASE_AND_MATTRESS.html

I am ever so close, but just can't finish it off.My script is:

```
 base_url = 'http://www.bidorbuy.co.za/item/287281843/BEDS_DOUBLE_BED_POCKET_SPRING_BASE_AND_MATTRESS.html'
 source = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url).read()
 soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

 soup.find("span", class_ = "condition").find("span", class_ = "value-title")
```

the final line is the closest I get to extracting the new/used split. But the object I get, or the way the HTML is written, seems to be a different format to the other elements I am extracting

I can extract price and title fine (see code below), but I can link them simply with the div/span/class labels.

```
 soup.find("div", class_ = "big_price").find("span", class_="bigPriceText2").text
```

The new/used seems to be in a slightly different format that has me stumped. I have tried a few variations but none seem to work

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I just figured it out. I needed to extract the 'title' attribute from the Span with all the properties. So     a = soup.find("span", class_ = "condition").find("span", class_ = "value-title"), a.attrs['title']

Comment: Go ahead and answer the question in the answer section and accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I needed to extract the 'title' attribute from the Span with all the properties. So a = soup.find("span", class_ = "condition").find("span", class_ = "value-title"), a.attrs['title']